# Conditioned rule to fill in column of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe in R that looks like that:

```
df <- data.frame(Entity = c('Entity A', 'Entity B', 'Entity C'),
                Metric_1 = c('0.04', '0.002', '0.01'),
                Metric_2 = c('0.01', '0.005', '0.015'),
                Derived_metric = c('')
                )
```

I would like to create a rule to fill in automatically the column "Derived_metric", so that:

- If Metric_1 **or** Metric_2 is above 2%, assign value 3 to the Derived_metric;
- If Metric_1 **or** Metric_2 is above 1% but below 2%, assign value 2 to the Derived_metric;
- If Metric_1 **or** Metric_2 is below 1%, assign value 1 to the Derived_metric.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Convert Metric columns into numeric, then read about ifelse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Entity = c('Entity A', 'Entity B', 'Entity C'),
                 Metric_1 = c('0.04', '0.002', '0.01'),
                 Metric_2 = c('0.01', '0.005', '0.015'),
                 Derived_metric = c('')
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Derived_metric = case_when(
      (Metric_1 > 0.02 | Metric_2 > 0.02) ~ 3,
      (Metric_1 > 0.01 & Metric_1 < 0.02 | Metric_2 > 0.01 & Metric_2 < 0.02) ~ 2,
      (Metric_1 < 0.01 | Metric_2 < 0.01) ~ 1
    )
  )
  
#>     Entity Metric_1 Metric_2 Derived_metric
#> 1 Entity A     0.04     0.01              3
#> 2 Entity B    0.002    0.005              1
#> 3 Entity C     0.01    0.015              2
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple columns, we can create the condition in `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Derived_metric = case_when(if_any(starts_with("Metric_"), 
   ~ .x > 0.02)~ 3, 
  if_any(starts_with("Metric_"), ~ between(.x, 0.01, 0.2)) ~ 2, 
   if_any(starts_with("Metric_"), ~ .x < 0.01)~ 1))
```

-output

```
      Entity Metric_1 Metric_2 Derived_metric
1 Entity A    0.040    0.010              3
2 Entity B    0.002    0.005              1
3 Entity C    0.010    0.015              2
```